# Python: Imported matplotlib but cannot use imshow

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, matplotlib

I'm working in Ubuntu as Virtual-Box guest on top of Windows machine (as host), and I am attempting to run my python script from the terminal. I had difficulty installing matplotlib using pip install. I managed to install it using

> sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

However, I am unable to bring up an image I have created in my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as random
from random import randrange


image = plt.imshow(mymatrix)
plt.show()
```

If I import matplotlib as:

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

I am recieving the following error on attempting to run the script:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imshow'

If I import matplotlib as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I recieve the following error:

> raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
>   ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk
>   package

On attempting to install python-tk using 'pip install python-tk' this is what I'm getting:

> ~/ising $ pip install python-tk Collecting python-tk   Could not find
>   a version that satisfies the requirement python-tk (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for python-tk

I'm unsure if I have in fact incorrectly installed matplotlib from the beginning. I am aware pyplot is not automatically imported with matplotlib, could the same be true for installing it from the console? Seems like I have tried everything at this stage.

Comment: Its not clear from your question so I'll ask just in case: You are *first* importing matplotlib and *then* calling imshow, right?

Comment: yes. Will edit my question now

Comment: **DO NOT USE PIP** to "install the python-tk package". It is a system package, not a Python package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you do not have a graphical [backend](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) installed. The error you are getting about Python Tk is happening because normally Tk comes with any Python distribution, so you *should* have at least that. You can install any Python bindings for Tk, Pyqt4, Pyqt5, Wx, GTK, (possibly others) to get a working interactive graphical backend. Check the package repository for the actual package names to install.

Keep in mind that functions like `imshow` are part of the (sub)package `matplotlib.pyplot`, not `matplotlib` itself. `import matplotlib as plt` is simply wrong if you intend to do `plt.imshow(...)`. The correct import is either `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` or `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Answer (score -1):

According to  the documentation   [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) try this

```
 python -mpip install -U pip
 python -mpip install -U matplotlib
```

Comment: I only test it on windows :)